# How to create age groups from every age number in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset of people, each with a name, gender, age etc.
I want to group them into age group categories. I need a condition.

```
data = data.groupBy([ data['Age'] > 45 and data['Age'] <55))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need filter before `groupby`

```
data.query("Age> 45 and Age < 55").groupby('Age')
```